# Horizontally scrolling divs, white space of inner divs messed up

Tags: css

In order to enable a series of divs to be horizontally scrollable inside a fixed container, I use the ***white-space: nowrap*** as recommended in many places.

Unfortunately, this is being inherited by the inner divs and the text blends together of the inner divs. When I try to set the white-space at the inner div level, it breaks the scrolling.

```
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="x">
    asdfasdf
  </div>
  <div class="x">
    asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
  </div>
  <div class="x">
    asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
  </div>
  <div class="x">
    asdfasdf
  </div>
</div>

div.scroll {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  height: 40px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.x {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the jfiddle of the issue I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/wyhorxes/1/

How do I fix this?

Comment: you are setting a fixed width which is the culprit, simply remove it

Comment: @TemaniAfif What if i want the inner elements to have a fixed width?

Comment: rest white-space to normal and use vertical-align:top to align them to the top

Comment: what the issue? it's seems to be fine for me .. probably you need to clear your cache

Comment: The divs dont scroll properly as the jfiddle example does. just cleared cache and i'm getting same issue. it basically moves the entire screen left rather than scroll neatly through the divs like the jfiddle.

Comment: you are setting width:800px to the divs, you need to make it width:100% or add `max-width:100%`

Comment: the max-width:100% did it! thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `width: 800px` to `width: 100%`.  This way, `.x` will take up 100% of the screen width rather than just 800px no matter what the width of the screen is.